# Set CMD docker container without rebuilding

Tags: php, docker, mysqli

Can we change the CMD of the container.

this is what i did run

```
$ docker run -it stock_image sh
sh@docker # did some changes here
$ # exited container
$ docker commit [commit-id] new_image
```

I looked into `docker inpsect new_image` the CMD variable has been lost, I know it can be solved using build process using **Dockerfile** but I'm curious can we set docker image CMD any how?

Reason I want to do this, **docker-compose.yml** cannot set the CMD (i'm not sure, hoping it can do), since I have to do few changes entering the container using `docker exec` then commit it rather than re-doing the whole process.

P.S. i was adding `pdo pdo_mysql mysqli` to `php:7.2.5-fpm-alpine3.6` image

Comment: Docker compose can set a CMD, it's `command:`, and building using manual `docker commit` is an anti-pattern. Can you explain why those changes can't be done automatically?

Comment: @johnharris85 I was trying CMD in docker-compose, yes building with `docker commit` isn't the way but when you screw up your **dockerfile** you have to go through whole build from scratch process which takes lots of time, for quick and time saving go into container and change stuffs, also helpful doing iterative process.

Comment: docker will cache build layers so any change you make in your Dockerfile will result in only the layer for that change in your Dockerfile and any subsequent layers being rebuilt. So if your `CMD` was the last entry in your Dockerfile, changing it and rebuilding would be almost instant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can use Dockerfile commands upon "docker commit".

```
docker commit -c "CMD /my/new/app" [commit-id] new_image
```